# How to rotate marker in swift by heading?

Tags: swift, mapkit, real-time, mapkitannotation

[image]

Hi Guys i'm trying to update the location of this annotation by receiving heading from socket so every time i update the heading the image return to its original state then goes back to the new heading received from socket also after the update the image appears like it's rotated left from the heading received from socket(little deviation) here's the code i'm using to update the heading:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {


        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }
        let annotationIdentifier = "marker"
        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
         let unitAnnotation = annotation as? Unit
        if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
            annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }else {
            annotationView = unitAnnotation?.annotationView()

            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }


        if let annotationView = annotationView {

            annotationView.canShowCallout = true
            let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Arrow32")
                let imageHeight  = image.size.height
            annotationView.image = image
            annotationView.tintColor = UIColor.blue

         annotationView.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -imageHeight / 2)
            self.addBounceAnimationToView(view: annotationView)
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            if let heading = unitAnnotation?.heading{
                //annotationView?.annotation?.= unitAnnotation?.coordinate

            annotationView?.transform = self.mapKit.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(self.degreesToRadians(degrees: heading+20)))
            }
        }
        return annotationView

    }
```

Any Help will be much appreciated thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

```
locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()  



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                let angle = CGFloat(newHeading.trueHeading).toRadians
                self.markerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
            }
        }
```

An extension to convert to radians

```
extension CGFloat {
        var toRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
        var toDegrees: CGFloat { return self * 180 / .pi }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the old heading add it to the new one then make the transform

Comment: You mean adding old + new 
Every time there's new heading i'm updating the annotation so how adding the old will work if you explain to me that will be great

Comment: adding the new heading to the old will give the final result , suppose first angle was 30 , then comes 60 , total will be 90 instead of using 60 which how you implement it now

Comment: and what if the new heading is 180 i think after a while of updates it is going to be like 500 degree :D